# How to store dates and times in a database (stores date when user does an action)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am currently working on an app, which consists of a main view, and a table view. It is a simple game. In the game, all the scores consist of an Integer, and it is permanently stored inside an array. In the table view part of the game, it displays the user's scores in chronological order. The thing that I am trying to do is have it that the table view also prints out the date and time when the user gets a new score. 
I am trying to make it that when a user clicks a button, it stores the date and time in which the user clicked the button in an array, which I can then reference for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var dates: [NSDate] = []
    IBAction func dateAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        dates.append(NSDate())
    }
}
```

Tie the button that the user clicks on to the IBAction function from inside your storyboard and every time the user taps on the button, a new NSDate object, containing the date and time of the tap, will be appended to the dates array.